# Sorting an ArrayList is not working in a Recyclerview

Tags: android, sorting, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

I want to sort Items by its name in a recyclerview. But null point exception is occuring.

This is my sorting class.

```
public class ItemSorter {
    public void sortItemByName(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dealer) {
        Collections.sort(dealer, new Comparator<SuggestGetSet>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(SuggestGetSet suggestGetSet, SuggestGetSet t1) {
                return suggestGetSet.getName().compareTo(t1.getName());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This is my SuggestGetSet class

```
public class SuggestGetSet {

    String dealer_id, rep_id, dealer_name;

    public SuggestGetSet() {

    }

    public SuggestGetSet(String dealer_id, String id, String name) {
        this.dealer_id=dealer_id;
        this.rep_id=id;
        this.dealer_name=name;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return rep_id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.rep_id = id;
    }

    public String getDealerId() {
        return dealer_id;
    }

    public void setDealerId(String dealer_id) {
        this.dealer_id = dealer_id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return dealer_name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.dealer_name = name;
    }
 }
```

This is my Fragment class which I am use my sorting method.

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_dealer_list, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.dealerListRecyclerView);

        repNo = UserLogIn.getRepNo();

        getJsonRequest();
```

This is the button which I am use to sort by name

```
         sortButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sortByName);
         sortButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                itemSorter.sortItemByName(dealerList);
                dlAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),dealerList.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    private void getJsonRequest() {

        final SQLiteHandler sqLiteHandler = new SQLiteHandler(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        Cursor cr = sqLiteHandler.getData(sqLiteHandler);
        cr.moveToFirst();

        do {
            repNo = cr.getString(0);
        } while (cr.moveToNext());
        cr.close();

        CustomJsonObjectRequest request = new CustomJsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_JSON_DEALER_LIST, hashMap, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(String.valueOf(response));
                    if (jsonObject.names().get(0).equals("feed")) {
                        dealerList = parseJsonResponse(response);
                        dlAdapter.setDealertList(dealerList);

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No Dealers Available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                /*dealerList = parseJsonResponse(response);
                dlAdapter.setDealertList(dealerList);*/
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        }) {
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                hashMap.put("repNo", repNo);
                return hashMap;
            }
        };
        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> parseJsonResponse(JSONObject response) {
        ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> groupList = new ArrayList<>();
        if (response != null || response.length() > 0) {

            try {

                JSONArray arrayDelaers = response.getJSONArray(KEY_FEED_NAME);

                for (int i = 0; i < arrayDelaers.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject currentObject = arrayDelaers.getJSONObject(i);
                    String rep = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_ID);
                    String name = currentObject.getString(KEY_REP_NAME);
                    String dealerId = currentObject.getString(KEY_DEALER_ID);

                    SuggestGetSet delaers = new SuggestGetSet();
                    delaers.setId(rep);
                    delaers.setName(name);
                    delaers.setDealerId(dealerId);

                    groupList.add(delaers);

                }
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), productList.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return groupList;
    }

    public static interface ClickListener {
        public void onClick(View view, int position);

        //public void onLongClick(View view, int position);

    }
```

My LogCat

```
04-03 18:18:05.039 6347-6347/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-03 18:18:05.039 6347-6347/com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                            Process: com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat, PID: 6347
                                                                                            java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.ItemSorter.sortItemByName(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
                                                                                                at com.ceatkelanisrilanka.dushanmadushanka.ceat.fragments.YourDealerListFragment$1.onClick(YourDealerListFragment.java:145)
                                                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: post your `logcat` error ?

Comment: Show the stack trace, the text that says it is a null pointer exception.

Comment: Where did you instantiate your `itemSorter`?

Comment: @JoelMin Inside the onClick method in onCreatView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do. Seems like your `ItemSorter` is just an utility class, so just add a `static` decorator to your sort method like this: `public static void sortItemByName(ArrayList<SuggestGetSet> dealer)`

Then if you want to use it, just call the method on the class directly: `ItemSorter.sortItemByName(dealerList)`. This eliminates the need to instantiate the class and hence avoiding NullPointerException.

However if you do not wish to make your method static, then you need to make sure your `itemSorter` has been initialised somewhere before you call the method.